# Оформление "подтекста" боковыми линиями

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, оформление

Каким способом возможно реализовать такие боковые линии, используя только HTML, CSS

[image: Скриншот с pdf макета]

Comment: можно например бэкграунд градиентом или бордерами псевдоэлементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.text {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.text::before,
.text::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.75rem
}

.text::after {
    right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="text">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white);
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team of professionals</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team<br/> of professionals <br/> здесь нет линии</h3>
```

**Линия с градиентным эффектом с обеих сторон контента:**

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.heading:before, .heading-ie span.before{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white);
}
.heading:after, .heading-ie span.after{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, white);
}

/* Just for demo*/
body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team of professinals</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>We are a team<br/> of professinals <br/> no. of lines</h3>
```